# groupBy operator, items from different groups interleaved

Tags: rx-java

The following code:

```
    Observable
            .just(0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9)
            .doOnNext(item -> System.out.println("source emitting " + item))
            .groupBy(item -> {
                System.out.println("groupBy called for " + item);
                return item % 3;
            })
            .subscribe(observable -> {
                System.out.println("got observable " + observable + " for key " + observable.getKey());
                observable.subscribe(item -> {
                    System.out.println("key " + observable.getKey() + ", item " + item);
                });
            });
```

leaves me perplexed. The output I get is:

```
    source emitting 0
    groupBy called for 0
    got observable rx.observables.GroupedObservable@42110406 for key 0
    key 0, item 0
    source emitting 1
    groupBy called for 1
    got observable rx.observables.GroupedObservable@1698c449 for key 1
    key 1, item 1
    source emitting 2
    groupBy called for 2
    got observable rx.observables.GroupedObservable@5ef04b5 for key 2
    key 2, item 2
    source emitting 3
    groupBy called for 3
    key 0, item 3
    source emitting 4
    groupBy called for 4
    key 1, item 4
    source emitting 5
    groupBy called for 5
    key 2, item 5
    source emitting 6
    groupBy called for 6
    key 0, item 6
    source emitting 7
    groupBy called for 7
    key 1, item 7
    source emitting 8
    groupBy called for 8
    key 2, item 8
    source emitting 9
    groupBy called for 9
    key 0, item 9
```

So, in the top level subscribe method, I get 3 observables from the GroupedObservable, as expected. Then, one by one, I subscribe to the grouped observables - and here the thing I don't understand:

Why are the original items still emitted in the original sequence (i.e. 0, 1, 2, 3, ...) and not 0, 3, 6, 9 ... for key 0, followed by 1, 4, 7 for key 1, followed by 2, 5, 8 for key 2?

I think I understand how the groups are created:

```
1. 0 is emitted, the key function is called and it gets 0
2. it is checked if an observable for 0 exists, it doesn't, so a new one is created and emitted, and then it emits 0
3. the same happens for source items 1 and 2 as they both create new groups, and observables with key 1 and 2 are emitted, and they emit 1 and 2 correspondingly
4. source item 3 is emitted, the key function is called and it gets 0
5. it is checked if an observable for 0 exists, it does -> no new grouped observable is created nor emitted, but 3 is emitted by the already existing observable
6. etc. until the source sequence is drained
```

It seems that although I get the grouped observables one by one, their emissions are somehow interleaved. How does this happen?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Why are the original items still emitted in the original sequence (i.e. 0, 1, 2, 3, ...) and not 0, 3, 6, 9 ... for key 0, followed by 1, 4, 7 for key 1, followed by 2, 5, 8 for key 2?

You've answered your own question. You're operating on a stream of items, in the order they're emitted. So as each one is emitted, it gets passed down the operator chain and you see the output you've shown here.

The alternative output you're expecting there requires the chain to wait until the source has stopped emitting items for *all* groups. Say you had `Observable.just(0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 0)`. Then you'd expect (0, 3, 0), (1, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4), (2) as your output groups. What if you had an infinite stream of 4's? Your subscriber would never receive that 0, 3..  from the first group.

You can create the behaviour you're looking for. The `toList` operator will cache output until the source completes, and then pass a `List<R>` to the subscriber:

```
.subscribe(observable -> {
    System.out.println("got observable " + observable + " for key " + observable.getKey());
    observable.toList().subscribe(items -> {
        // items is a List<Integer>
        System.out.println("key " + observable.getKey() + ", items " + items);
    });
});
```

Comment: I know about the toList() trick. I also know that this behavior makes sense, and you example is very good at showing why. My I am rather at a loss about how it is implemented the way it works. I get 3 observables, and I subscribe to them as they are emitted by the grouping - but how can it be interleaved? It as if the 3 subscriptions were happening immediately and the emissions were kind of asynchronous later. Could you shed some light on that?

Comment: The 3 subscriptions for the different groups happen when a new 'group' is created, on-demand. The emissions are actually happening _synchronously_ - since this is all on the same thread, each one has to finish being processed before the next one can be handled. I think that's probably the key point you're missing?

Comment: 'all on the same thread, each one has to finish being processed before the next one can be handled' - this is exactly what I don't get. The output shows that the are all kind of handled at the same time; it's not that the first group is first consumed and then the next comes into the picture - their emissions are interleaved with each other.

Comment: Think of `groupBy` as a routing mechanism, so as each item is emitted from the first observable, the `groupBy` function routes that item to the appropriate observer (creating it if necessary). [The marble diagram in the docs](http://reactivex.io/documentation/operators/groupby.html) actually shows the timeline behaviour you're anticipating, I think, which is unfortunate (it shows the circles all coming out before the triangles).

Comment: Yes, the marble diagram is making things confusing. But, I guess I got it, your routing tip and my own trial and error with the code help. So basically, the way I understand it: once a new grouped observable is first created, I can subscribe to it, which says: 'I am interested in emission which would land in this group'. Then, for each number, a group (either newly created or looked-up) is checked for a subscriber, and if there exists one, its onNext() is called.

Comment: So basically, the nested subscriptions on the grouped observables are like a yes/no switch which tell the main subscriber whether it should route, as you put it, certain emissions to their grouped observables.

Comment: I've a related [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38987925/rxjava-flight-data-streaming-parallel-processing-with-groupby) regarding `groupBy`, except that I want the groups to be processed simultaneously. Could you to take a look?